# Initialize JS object with one of its prototypes

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have the following Javascript class

```
var Score = function (roll, category) {
this.roll = [];
this.category = category;
};

Score.prototype.getRoll = function () {
    return this.roll;
};

Score.prototype.ones = function() {
    this.roll.filter((i) => i == 1)
    .reduce((sum, i) => sum + i);
};

module.exports.Score = Score;
```

which I'm trying to test with Mocha and Chai like so:

```
var Score = require('../src/Score.js');
describe('Score', function() {
    var score = new Score([1,2,3,4,5], this.ones);
    expect(score).to.be.of.type(Score);

    describe('ones', function() {

    });
});
```

I get, however, an error claiming that Score is not a constructor, which doesn't surprise me. I am in doubt how to develop this construct and if there is a better way to achieve my aim. In case that's not clear: Score is a class that will score a particular game when given a roll and a rule to score, the latter being one of the prototypes of the function. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: in your constructor you don't assign `roll` param

Comment: do you export your `Score` class?

Comment: What do you expect `this.ones` to be in the test `describe` callback?

Comment: I did export it, just forgot to write it here. Updated the question. I cannot console log score as the error happens on line 4 `var score = new Score([1,2,3,4,5], this.ones);`

Comment: Export like this `module.exports = Score;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your export doesn't match your import. You export a plain object (`module.exports`) which has a property called `Score` which is a function (constructor). But the other file expects it to export the constructor itself. So either change the test file to `var Score = require('../src/Score.js').Score;`, or change the other file to `module.exports = Score;`. (The latter will of course affect any other scripts that import this one.)